# How can I pass props to children of children in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I would like to pass a prop to children of children, below codes snippet describes my problem.

Here is an example about the problem I want to pass **name** property to `<MyComponent />` without prop drilling.

```
<ParentComponent name="name">
    <ChildComponent>
        <MyComponent />
    </ChildComponent>
    <ChildComponent/>
        <MyComponent />
    </ChildComponent>
</ParentComponent>
```

Inside of the `<ParentComponent />`:

```
Children.map(children, (child) => {
        return Children.map(child.props.children, (innerChild, index) => {
            return cloneElement(innerChild as ReactElement, {
                name: `${index}-name`,
            });
        });
    });
```

`<MyComponent />`:

```
const MyComponent = ({name}) => {
  console.log(name); // name is undefined

  return (
    <div id={`${name}-component`}>...</div>
  )
}
```

Unfortunately the name property is `undefined` when I try to access it.

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The solution will be to use state management tool:
redux, flux or react context API 
which can help you in the future for managing even more complex state.

Comment: As mentioned above, the context system would be my go-to: https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context

Comment: https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement is legacy api.

Comment: I know a lot about contexts I love to use redux and contexts for deeply nested components. Just in this case I want to solve the issue with Children.map and cloneElement method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass a prop to deeply nested children without prop drilling, you can use React's Context API. Context allows you to share values like this across the component tree without having to pass the props explicitly through each level.

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

const NameContext = createContext();

export const useName = () => {
  const context = useContext(NameContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useName must be used within a NameProvider');
  }
  return context;
};

export const NameProvider = ({ children, name }) => {
  return (
    <NameContext.Provider value={name}>
      {children}
    </NameContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Now you should modify your component to use this context:

```
import React from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';
import { NameProvider } from './NameContext'; // Import the NameProvider

const ParentComponent = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <NameProvider name={name}> {/* Provide the 'name' prop */}
      <div>
        <ChildComponent>
          <MyComponent />
        </ChildComponent>
        <ChildComponent>
          <MyComponent />
        </ChildComponent>
      </div>
    </NameProvider>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;
```

And also modify `MyComponent` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useName } from './NameContext'; // Use the useName hook to access the 'name' prop

const MyComponent = () => {
  const name = useName(); // Access the 'name' prop using the hook

  return (
    <div id={`${name}-component`}>
      {name}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```